# How do I distinguish file from folder in php?

Tags: php, file, web, directory

I am creating a program that searches a specified directory and creates an un-ordered list from that directory.  I needed a function to distinguish between a file and a folder, so I created my own, which serves my purpose for now, but seems to be a very dirty way of doing things and might cause problems for me down the road.  This is the function:

```
function isFolder($string)
{
    $isFolder = true;
    $str_array = str_split($string);
    $counter = 0;
    while($counter < count($str_array))
    {
        if($str_array[$counter] == '.') {
            $isFolder = false;
            break;
        } else {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    return $isFolder;
}
```

It checks to see if there is a period in the name of whatever it is it is scanning.  Is there a function to distinguish the two, or at least a better way to implement this?

Comment: use  is_dir() php function. Details : http://bd1.php.net/is_dir

Comment: Put that as the answer.

Comment: I remember seeing is_dir() before.  Doesn't work with me for some reason.  The issue must be somewhere else in the code.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `is_dir()` php function.

Details : https://www.php.net/is_dir

```
if(is_dir($string)){
// folder
}
else{
//file
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this

```
var_dump(is_dir('foo.txt'));
var_dump(is_dir('foo/bar'));
```

which will return

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

check [is_dir](http://php.net/is_dir) for more examples

Answer (score 2):

`SplFileInfo` or `is_dir` can help.

```
<?php
function isFolder($path) {
    $path = new SplFileInfo($path);
    return $path->isDir();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [is_dir](http://php.net/is_dir) to check whether it's a file or [is_file](http://php.net/is_file) to check if it's a file.

Answer (score 0):

try using the function `id_dir`: http://php.net/is_dir